# Regular expression to replace period in name portion of e-mail header?

Tags: php, regex, email, string

I am attempting to send an e-mail in PHP and the system is rejecting the e-mail because the name portion of the e-mail address contains a period like below:

```
 Mr. Joe Nobody <jo_nobody@nowhere.com>
```

I am looking for an elegant solution to replace all periods that are not part of the e-mail address with either a space or no character at all. My problem is that the field I am replacing may contain more than one name/e-mail address combination like so:

```
 Mr. Joe Nobody <joe_nobody@here.com>, Mrs. Jane Noone <jane_noone@there.com>
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this in PHP using either standard string manipulation or a regular expression?

Comment: I recommend exploding the expression by ',' before doing anything else.

Comment: Can we safely assume there will be no `<` and `>` symbols in the name portion?

Comment: Instead of potentially bastardizing someone's name, why not fix the "system" that is rejecting the email?  Are you sure you are using the API correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex pattern should work in PHP:

Search Pattern :  `\.(?=[^<]*<)`

Replace Pattern:  a space, underline, or none

for example:

```
  $email = 'Mr. Joe Nobody <joe_nobody@here.com>';
  $email = preg_replace('/\.(?=[^<]*<)/', '_', $email);
```

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the answer. I'll repost if I find a better way to handle this situation, but you did indeed answer my question with an elegant solution, so thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments above, this really shouldn't be required by an email system.  Having said that, you could remove periods from the address, ignoring anything between "<..>" with the following

```
$a="Mr. Joe Nobody <joe_nobody@here.com>, Mrs. Jane Noone <jane_noone@there.com>";
$b=preg_replace("/([^<.]*)(\.|(<.*?>))/", "$1$3",$a); 
echo $b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
foreach(imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist('Mr. Joe Nobody <joe_nobody@here.com>, Mrs. Jane Noone <jane_noone@there.com>','') as $address){
   $result[] = preg_replace('/\.\s?/',' ',$address->personal)
      .' <'.$address->mailbox
      .'@'.$address->host.'>';
}
echo implode(', ',$result);
```

But I do agree with Ether's comment, there should be no need.

Comment: +1 - I agree that this shouldn't be necessary, but I haven't found a way around it yet. I'll repost here if I find a better solution.